# Ajuda com consulta Sql Concatenação

Tags: sql, servidor

tenho esta tabela faço a seguinte consulta

SELECT top 5 '0' as id, a.DataHora,a.Percentual as dados,'Nível - R1 - 4000 m³' as tipoanalogica FROM [Nivel_A1_Valadares_EAT_Altinopolis] As a order by a.DataHora desc

que me da este resutado

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

só que preciso que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ou seja os dados sejam colocados na mesma linha.

já usei pivot mas não consegui. será que tem como?

Comment: PIVOT é a solução , ou o padrão do SGBD (não informado) ou fazendo por CASE IIF etc.

Answer (score -3):

resolvido para quem precisar no futuro:

```
SELECT * fROM ( SELECT  top 5 '0' as id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@ROWCOUNT desc) AS coluna,a.Percentual as dados,'Nível - R1 - 4000 m³' as tipoanalogica FROM [Nivel_A1_Valadares_EAT_Altinopolis] As a group by a.DataHora, a.Percentual) em_linhas pivot (sum(dados) for coluna in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5])) em_colunas order by 1
```